# Correct Windowing Effect at Amplitude Scale

Tags: matlab, dft, power-spectral-density, window-functions, sinad

I am trying verify the noise floor returned by Matlab `sinad()`. I am able to get the results matching by summing power spectrum density with $\frac{f_\text{s}}{N}$. But I am not able to match the results by following Parseval's theorem to root sum square the $X[k]$.

$$ S_1=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \big|w[n]\big| $$
$$ S_2=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \big|w[n]^2\big| $$

where $w[n]$ is a window function.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \big|x[n]\big|^2 = \frac{1}{S_1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\big|X[k]\big|^2
$$

My thought was to apply windows DC gain correction at $X[k]$ amplitude scale (not power scale). This relation works if the windowing function is Uniform, so obviously I am missing something.

Thanks to @Dan Boschen and @OverLordGoldDragon, I realized there are two errors:

1. Because this is non-coherent signals, the correction factor is $S_2$ rather than $S_1$. And correction is applied to power not amplitude.
2. The dividing factor should still be $frac{1}{N}$. Correction made within the summing operation.

Therefore the Parseval's equation becomes:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \big|x[n]\big|^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{X[k]^2}{S_2}
$$

Here is revised test code. All results match.

```
rng(1)
fs = 500;   % sampling frequency
T = 1000;
t = 0:1/fs:T-1/fs;
Fs = 100;    % natural frequency
data = cos(2*pi*Fs*t) + 0.011*randn(size(t));
N = length(data);
F=fs*(0:(N/2))/N;

% Kaiser window used by sinad(), beta=38
win = kaiser(N,38);
data_fft_full_abs_k=abs(fft(win.*data'));
data_fft_full_abs_k = data_fft_full_abs_k(1:N/2+1);
S1=sum(win);
S2=sum(win.^2);
ENBW_hz=fs*S2/(S1^2);

% find the range of signal spectrum
[peak_fft,peak_freq_idx]=max(data_fft_full_abs_k);
idxLeft = peak_freq_idx-1;
idxRight = peak_freq_idx+1;
while idxLeft > 0 && data_fft_full_abs_k(idxLeft) <= data_fft_full_abs_k(idxLeft+1)
    idxLeft = idxLeft - 1;
end
while idxRight < N && data_fft_full_abs_k(idxRight-1) >= data_fft_full_abs_k(idxRight)
    idxRight = idxRight + 1;
end
idxLeft = idxLeft + 1;
idxRight = idxRight - 1;
% remove the signals
data_fft_full_abs_k(idxLeft:idxRight)=0;

% calculate rms with amplitude correction
% revert to double sided before calculating root sum square
data_fft_full_abs_k=vertcat(data_fft_full_abs_k,data_fft_full_abs_k(2:length(data_fft_full_abs_k)-1));
noise_fft_rss=rssq(sqrt(data_fft_full_abs_k.^2/S2))/sqrt(N)

% calculate rms with correct at psd
data_fft_full_power=data_fft_full_abs_k.^2;
data_fft_power=(2/S1^2)*data_fft_full_power(1:N/2+1);
data_fft_psd=data_fft_power./ENBW_hz; % 2/(fs*S2)*data_fft_power
noise_psd=sqrt(sum(data_fft_psd*fs/N))

% calculate rms with sinad()
[snrad_dB,dist_noise_pw_dB]=sinad(data,fs);
noise_floor_rms_sinad=sqrt(10^(dist_noise_pw_dB/10))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/52960/21048

Comment: Thanks. It helps me to realize correction factor should be the non-coherent correction factor. Updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: So is there still a question? If the problem is solved and the answer helped, great - you should +1 and accept the answer. Otherwise edit the question, but note that StackExchange isn't for extended back-forths, and it's preferred to ask a new question for new/developed problems. And FYI, the right side of your equations may be correct for what you're trying to achieve, but none of the equations themselves are correct; it's $\sum |x|^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum |X|^2$.

Comment: Thank you. I just up voted your answer and Dan Boschen's comment. I don't think your answer itself completely answered the question so I will not accept it as an answer to not confuse future viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations:

- Your Parseval equation is incorrect, should be $\frac{1}{N^3}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|X[k] * W[k]|^2$, where $*$ is circular convolution and FFT is such that iFFT does `1/N`; $w[n]$ can in no way move outside the summation on right hand side
- Below I ignore `sqrt` everywhere
- `noise_fft_rms` is doing `sum((data_fft_full_abs_k/S1)^2)`; this does not implement your equation, move `S1` out
- `noise_psd` is doing `sum(data_fft_full_abs_k.^2) / (N*S2)`, which is very different and won't match any formulation in terms of `S1` in the general case

Parseval-Plancherel's is just a way of computing signal energy in frequency domain; I don't know what `sinad` is but it clearly does more than that. The norm by `1/S1` is for matching peak value with signal amplitude, as shown [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86731/50076) - that's different from Parseval's. I'd check your definitions.

Comment: Both my original Parseval equation and your edited Parseval equation are correct. Mine is implied be with Uniform window, yours is explicitly with window w(n). However, when talking about a signal's average power rms, Uniform window is used in time domain. That is why I am trying to correct non Uniform window (Kaiser in this case) to match with Uniform window time domain rms.

Please correct my post back to its original form.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that it was not modified by you. It was the first editor who incorrectly changed my equations. So my original post's equation was correct, and your equation is also correct.

Comment: @JohnL The original isn't correct either, $1/S_1$ should be $1/N$.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, it should be $\frac{1}{N}$. Updated my post.